# Is spousal abuse primarily initiated by males?

Tags: gender, marriage

Avoiding exceptions for same-sex couples, is abuse in heterosexual couples more commonly initiated by the husband? I am mostly interested in physical violence that is non-reciprocal. In other words, in a couple where only one spouse beats the other, is it significantly more common for the man to beat the women?

This belief seems stemmed from the idea that men are more violent and are physically stronger. "Wife-beater" is a commonly heard accusation; I cannot recall hearing *any* stories of "husband-beaters". I have also seen claims by mens rights groups suggesting that women are more often the abuser in such a relationship. Given the contended point, is there a statistical difference between the initiating gender?

Comment: I am certain there is a difference statistically, but I have personally witnessed husband beaters. They do exist and it is often a surprise to people. The numbers? No idea.

Comment: There’s more than just *physical* abuse. Those mens’ rights groups *might* refer to psychological abuse. I’m just speculating, mind.

Comment: @Konrad: Agreed. I limited the scope of this question mostly to help keep answers shorter / more focused and because I figured physical abuse is less inherently subjective / easier to study.

Comment: Please note that OBVIOUS answers/studies (e.g. results of surveys) are probably incredibly skewed - a lot of men would NEVER admit to the fact that "a girl beat me". Even to a survey.

Comment: Also, an interesting point to consider is whetherv the results might be influenced one way or another by BDSM culture. Plenty of people (both M and F) end up in a BDSM situation who would otherwise be part of domestic violence statistics, and the M/F ratio might also skew domestic violence picture either way.

Comment: And yet a third point is that you also need to account for non-heterosexual couples  - while it IS quite possible that including them would balance the impact out, it is impossible to predict that without actually studying. For example what if (hypothetical BS assumption) a large chunk of female would-be abusers have a significantly higher chance to end up in a lesbian relationship? Then the answer for heterosexual couples would down-play female propensity for violence in domestic situation. Or vice versa.

Comment: @DVK: Your last point is very good but I am personally interested in any disparity between violence in hetero couples. I don't know how to sift out "same-sex" results in reports that don't record it... so I don't really know where that leaves the results. My intent was to help narrow the scope but if it is easier to ignore the difference than I can edit the restriction out. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @MrHen:  DVK makes an excellent point that I think shouldn't be overlooked as it's important for a better understanding of the statistics (which I suspect would already be skewed anyway since men are more likely to "try to cope with it" rather than going through the embarrassment of admitting that they were "beat up by a girl"), especially if your purpose is to compare the violence exhibited by men vs. women.  @DVK's theory, that some violent women may (intentionally?) choose a female mate (because it's easier to be a bully to someone who is more likely weaker?), seems plausible.

Comment: I think one more criticism of this question is in order: How do you define "initiated"? If you define it has "strikes the first blow", you are ignoring everything that led up to the escalation, which often can involve considerable psychological abuse.

Comment: @Lager: The problem you point out is valid but it is far outside of a reasonable scope for this question. This question isn't trying to suggest there is or isn't a legitimate reason to initiate physical abuse. It just wants to know who initiated it. In other words, we cannot concern ourselves with _why_ something happened until we know _what_ happened.

Comment: @MrHen True. It's just that questions like this are often welcome fodder for misogynists who try to marginalize spousal abuse of women by men.

Comment: *Avoiding exceptions for same-sex couples*. Do you mean, *With exceptions* or *Allowing for exceptions* or *With the exception of* or something else?

Comment: @TRiG: Data that reports on spousal abuse by gender is unlikely to include information on the gender of the abused -- or, in other words, if an abuser is male did they abuse a female or another male? This question is explicitly ignoring that problem for now and just asking the simplified question, "Do male or females initiate more spousal abuse?"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Statistics don't always agree on this issue.

According to [this](http://ajph.aphapublications.org/cgi/reprint/97/5/941) study:

> Almost 24% of all relationships had
> some violence, and half (49.7%) of
> those were reciprocally violent. **In
> nonreciprocally violent relationships,
> women were the perpetrators in more
> than 70% of the cases.** Reciprocity was
> associated with more frequent violence
> among women (adjusted odds ratio
> [AOR]=2.3; 95% confidence interval
> [CI]=1.9, 2.8), but not men (AOR=1.26;
> 95% CI=0.9, 1.7). Regarding injury,
> men were more likely to inflict injury
> than were women (AOR=1.3; 95% CI=1.1,
> 1.5), and reciprocal intimate partner violence was associated with greater
> injury than was nonreciprocal intimate
> partner violence regardless of the
> gender of the perpetrator (AOR=4.4;
> 95% CI=3.6, 5.5).

Methodology looks rock solid to me:

> We analyzed data on young US adults
> aged 18 to 28 years from the 2001
> National Longitudinal Study of
> Adolescent Health, which contained
> information about partner violence and
> injury reported by 11 370 respondents
> on 18761 heterosexual relationships.

The idea that men are stronger, I think is obviously true - which leads to women being more likely to suffer injuries. However, according to this study and others, women can be plenty aggressive as well, and it often seems as if society simply ignores this fact.

Although apparently there's no shortage of **physical** violence of women against men, it is true that you won't see this often in the mainstream media. But it [does](http://www.guardian.co.uk/society/2010/sep/05/men-victims-domestic-violence) happen, occasionally. Quote from the [study](http://www.mankind.org.uk/pdfs/DVGovtStatsJan08.pdf) discussed in the Guardian article:

> For the year preceding the survey, and
> excluding stalking, **5.6% of women and
> 4.1% of men reported having suffered non-sexual partner abuse (any abuse,
> threat, or force from a partner or
> ex-partner), a proportion of male
> victims of about 42%. Of these, 2.7%
> of women and 2.0% of men reported
> suffering actual force [assault or
> violence], a proportion of male
> victims of about 43%, which was
> designated as ‘severe’ in the case of
> 1.8% of women and 1.6% of men, a proportion of male victims of about
> 47%.** These proportions are slightly
> higher than those found by Study 276
> some four years earlier. Such
> proportions of male victims are almost
> double those found by the BCS of
> 2004/05 (23% based on numbers of
> incidents) and that of 2005/06 (20%).
> **This suggests either a significant
> level of under-reporting especially by
> male victims of domestic abuse to
> these routine annual surveys or that
> basing the proportion on the numbers
> of incidents distorts the actual
> prevalence of male victims.**

To summarize: **existing research doesn't necessarily support the stereotype of an abusive male partner**, violence seems to be a problem for both genders.

Comment: Your statistics in Exhibit 1 do not differentiate between "violence done to men by women" and "violence done to men by men", and is therefore not relevant here.

Comment: well spotted @Ernie; I removed the irrelevant statistics.

Answer (score 13):

[This page](http://www.dvrc-or.org/domestic/violence/resources/C61/) gives statistics:

> Women accounted for 85% of the victims of intimate partner violence, men for approximately 15%.
>   *(Bureau of Justice Statistics Crime Data Brief, Intimate Partner Violence, 1993-2001, February 2003)*

However it also says:

> Surveys find that men and women assault one another and strike the first blow at approximately equal rates. 
>   *(Archer, J. (2000).  Sex differences in aggression between heterosexual partners:  A meta-analytic review.  Psychological Bulletin, 126 (5), 651-680.
>   Dutton, D., Kwong, M., & Bartholomew, K. (1999).  Gender differences in patterns of relationship violence in Alberta.  Canadian Journal of Behavioural Science, 31, 150-160
>   Morse, B. (1995).  Beyond the Conflict Tactics Scale:  Assessing gender differences in partner violence.  Violence and Victims, 10 (4), 251-269.
>   Straus, M. (1993).  Physical assaults by wives:  A major social problem.  In R. Gelles & D. Loseky (Eds.), Current controversies on family violence (pp. 67-87).  Newbury Park, CA:  Sage.)*

I can only speculate that the first refers to reported crimes, and the second to all forms of aggression.

Comment: That page also has some other relevant numbers. Some of them conflict the 85%/15% numbers. One example: "Surveys find that men and women assault one another and strike the first blow at approximately equal rates." Another: "Between 600,000 and 6 million women are victims of domestic violence each year, and between 100,000 and 6 million men, depending on the type of survey used to obtain the data." But great page link. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have also seen claims by mens rights groups suggesting that women are more often the abuser in such a relationship.

In some countries, the term "spousal abuse" isn't limited to physical violence. For example according to [this Canadian government definition](http://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/pi/fv-vf/facts-info/sa-vc.html) it includes:

> - Physical abuse
> - Sexual abuse and exploitation (includes ... using ridicule or other tactics to try to denigrate, control or limit their sexuality)
> - Emotional abuse (includes verbal attacks, such as yelling, screaming and name-calling.  Using criticism, verbal threats, social isolation, ... threatening a person or their loved ones, damaging their possessions, or harming their pets)
> - Economic or financial abuse includes stealing from or defrauding a partner
> - Spiritual abuse

According to that same document, "women are more likely to report being assaulted" in almost every category of abuse.

Comment: It is important to note these more "subtle" forms of abuse, and also that there may be a gender bias in the use of such, but a lack of recording of these.

Comment: -1 **women are more likely to report being assaulted** does not necessarily mean **primarily initiated by males** since not every abuse is reported. (see other 2 answers)

Comment: @Stefan I didn't claim it does "necessarily mean primarily initiated by males". I was carefully quoting the referenced/evidence FYI, not jumping to an unwarranted conclusion based on it. In fact I agree with your conclusion (that it "does not necessarily mean primarily initiated by males").